# How to throw an exception in the following C++ code

Tags: c++, exception

My class `SystemManager()` has a private object called `myObject` whose constructor requires an instance of another class.

How can I throw an exception in case `new` fails?

The.cpp:

```
SystemManager::SystemManager(): myObject(new TCPServer()) {  
    ...
}
```

The .h:

```
class SystemManager{
    ...
    MyObject myObject;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case `new` already throws an exception, but imagine others cases, where you don't use `new` operator, for example:

```
MyClass::MyClass( int var1, int var2 )
    : m_var1( var1 ),
      m_obj2( var1 ) // If this one throws an exception,
                     // it can't be caught.
{
    try
    {
       // Constructor body.
    }
    catch( ... )
    { }
}
```

So, to catch an exception from the initializer list you have to use a special kind of try-catch

```
MyClass::MyClass( int var1, int var2 )
    try : m_var1( var1 ),
          m_obj2( var1 )    // Now I can catch the exception.
{
    // Constructor body.
}
catch( ... )
{ }
```

Source: https://weseetips.wordpress.com/tag/exception-from-constructor-initializer-list/

Comment: An exception is throw anyway with try catch function (once the catch is reached). but that allow to throw an other exception.

Answer (score 2):

`new` **already** throws an exception if it fails. If the constructor of `TCP_server` fails, then it also should throw an exception. So you don't have to do anything in the `SystemManager` ctor.